# Set-QADUser: cleaning up Displayname

Tags: powershell, active-directory, quest

**Hi!**

Some of my users have `lastname firstname` in AD and I'd like to clean this up.
Tried with the following snippet:

```
get-QADUser user | Set-QADUser -DisplayName "$($_.FirstName + ' '+$_.LastName)"
```

but

```
get-QADUser user | select displayname
```

shows blank `Displayname`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this way it works

```
$user = get-QADUser user

Set-QADUser -identity $user -DisplayName ( $($user.firstname) + " " + $($user.lastname) )
```

In your way I think the pipe doesn't work as aspected. Maybe try to do a `foreach-object`

Comment: Thank you! Works great. Would love to know what was wrong though:)

Comment: @Sune Have you tested your code using a foreach-object after the pipe?

Comment: No I haven't (I quickly moved on to the next problem;)). But isn't there only one object?

Comment: @Sune. Yes there'is only one, but from the piping point of view  this can works: `-DisplayName ( $_.firstname) + " " + $_.lastname) )` but I've not tested it.